# Hybris Powertool B2B demo is showing a 404

Tags: http-status-code-404, sap-commerce-cloud, b2b

I am new to Hybris, I have succeeded in standing up the Powertools B2B site and have discovered a 404 error.  I would like to learn how to trouble shoot this 404 error along with other such errors.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Start up the OOTB version of Hybris 1811 with Powertools B2B site configured
2. In Backoffice, change the password for user screwdriverslover@pronto-hw.com
3. Log into the Powertools storefront with user screwdriverslover@pronto-hw.com
4. In the upper right select **My Account > Returns History**

And you will get a big 404 page not found.

How would I go about tracking down this error?  While I seek the solution, the steps to find the solution are far more important to me right now.

Comment: Any log on the console? what is the Returns History URL which you are trying to hit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the log (console or log file) to find the root cause.

The page/component you are trying to access might not have been created as part of the initialization. In Hybris, the pages/components are part of the content catalog. If the page/component you are trying to access has not have been created, you will need to import relevant ImpEx. The other possibility might be the wrong URL configured for this page. You can check all these things in the backoffice application.

***Update:*** copying the following text from my comment:-

You need to put into `localextensions.xml`, the extensions and addons responsible for order management. In the case of addons, you will also need to install the addon using `ant addoninstall`. A simple way to do it is to install `b2c_b2b_acc_oms` recipe. Alternatively, look into the `build.gradle` file of `b2c_b2b_acc_oms` for the OMS (Order Management System) extensions and addons and include/install them manually. When you are doing it manually, make sure to clean, build, and update your application using `ant clean all updatesystem`.

Comment: I totally understand what you are saying.  The problem is there is a BIG gap between what I know and getting to pages/components.  The ONLY think I know is that this is the URL that is not loading: https://powertools.local:9002/storefront/powertools/en/USD/my-account/returns . I was able to find the controllers in question: AccountReturnsPageController, CancelReturnPageController, or ReturnOrderPageController.  But I don't know backoffice/smartedit well enough to know how to figure how which pages those are connected to.  Might you be able to provide insight?